# org.apache.http.client.fluent corrupts URL

Tags: java, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have such URL https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&origins=Belarus,Minsk,Kuprevicha,1/2&destinations=Belarus,Minsk,Kurchatova,8&key={API_key} and in brovser it counts distance correctly:

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "ул. Курчатова 8, Минск, Беларусь" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [
      "ул. Академика Купревича 1/2, Минск 220141, Беларусь"
   ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "24,5 км",
                  "value" : 24526
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "20 мин.",
                  "value" : 1196
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

but when I use org.apache.http.client.fluent.Request:

```
String req = Request.Get(uri).execute().handleResponse(UTF8_CONTENT_HANDLER);
```

After executing this code i have such result:

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "Minsk, Belarus" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Minsk, Belarus" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "1 m",
                  "value" : 0
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "1 min",
                  "value" : 0
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When I click on the link in Chrome I get the same response as with HttpClient. I doubt this problem has anything to do with HttpClient. Capture packets transmitted with your browser, compare them with those generated by HttpClient and adjust your code accordingly

Answer (score 1):

The problem was not occused by apache Http Client. Google requires specify localiztion explicitely. Probaly for english localization it always works by default. If you append `&language=ru` to url, it will work correctly.