# Same request to Google Maps API works differently on various machines

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I registered [API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/start), and compossed the following url with it:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&origins=Belarus,Minsk,Kuprevicha,1/2&destinations=Belarus,Minsk,Kurchatova,8&key=AIzaSyBngdHtfv-gbJkhKbsgJMqU5T-BnacZuPI

I am getting responce where street information were erased:

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "Minsk, Belarus" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Minsk, Belarus" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "1 m",
                  "value" : 0
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "1 min",
                  "value" : 0
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

My colleague sitting next to me firing same request recieves a correct full responce.

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "ул. Курчатова 8, Минск, Беларусь" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [
      "ул. Академика Купревича 1/2, Минск 220141, Беларусь"
   ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "24,5 км",
                  "value" : 24526
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "20 мин.",
                  "value" : 1196
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

What is the reason of this weird behavior?

Comment: related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40532561/org-apache-http-client-fluent-corrupts-url

Comment: Is your colleague sending the same request? What does the response he is getting look like (the response to the "working" query). Your request is evaluating to from Minsk, Belarus to Minsk, Belarus (going nowhere).

Comment: @geocodezip, I edited my question

Comment: @geocodezip, if you append &language=be it starts work. weird.

Comment: Was your colleague using that in their request?  Do they have their computer/browser configured differently than yours (in particular with a language setting)?

Comment: Yes his local defined on OS level, he has `be` local and I have `en`

Comment: it works also with `language=ru`. `be` and `ru` is state languages in Belarus. For other languages that I tried, google erases street information.

Comment: I believe the language configuration of the OS is used by default if the language isn't specified in the request, but I'm not sure how that information is sent to the server in a request to the Web Service (as you indicated in your question), but perhaps it is sent in the headers when you use the browser to make the request.

Comment: Note that google isn't "erasing" the street information, it is geocoding the input information and getting different results (the desired address in one case, "Minsk, Belarus" for both source and destination in the other [which isn't particularly useful, as the directions don't go anywhere]).